# Create Email In Default Email Client Using Process.Start

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, email, mapi

I have an small office application (VB.Net) that manages a database of individuals based on a number of business rules. The user must be able to select individuals from that database to receive an email. The user wants to see the list of selected emails in their default email client as TO, CC and/or BCC items. The user will then supply a subject and email body and then send. There is no need to handle attachments or automatically send the email programmatically. The application simply needs to open the default email application with the addresses populated.

This functionality is currently implemented as an MS Access application which uses the DoCmd.SendObject method and can pass a list of several hundred emails to the default email client without any trouble.

I've used a mailto URI constructed with StringBuilder to specify the TO, CC, and BCC and then System.Diagnostics.Process.Start is used to open the default email client. This works great until the number of emails in the mailto URI increases. There appears to be a limit in the number of characters that can be passed via the Process.Start method.

I've tried to determine what other options there are but I've only seen:

- System.Web.Mail: Not desirable because the user will not and cannot provide SMTP configuration
- MAPI: This appears to be frowned upon.

Clearly there is some way to pass many addresses simultaneously since MS Access accomplishes it. How does one accomplish this?

Comment: What about breaking your user list into parts and send several emails?

Answer (score -1):

Try System.Web.Mail, but instead of having the user input the values, put some presets in.

A more desirable way of using this method is to have a server which has regularly updated presets. Your application can get then fetch this list and select the appropriate one.